# Why does my vue application is unable to run successfully with jQuery installed? Looking to import php/mysql backened database in vue

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I am quite new to web programming especially vuejs and jquery. First and foremost, I have looked into past similar posts but I am not sure what did I missed out.
I am currently looking to import the backend database from MySQL/PHP into my vuejs.
I have reference to ajax sample coding whereby they utilised jquery. Therefore, I am utilising jquery with vue-axios to import the data into the vue application. Before that, I have installed the jquery into the project directory and under the index.js file I added this portion of code. Besides that, I unable to locate the build/webpack.dev.conf.js inside the project. Before adding this portion of code, everything else in the application works fine.

```
window.$ = require('jquery')
window.JQuery = require('jquery')
```

Under the `main.js` file,

```
import jQuery from 'jquery'
global.jQuery = require('jquery')
var $ = global.jQuery
window.jQuery = window.$ = $ = jQuery
```

Furthermore, when I looked for errors (which is under the .vue file), under the vue ui command, where I built the project, it is as if the project doesn't recognize the `$(document).ready(function()`

> Unexpected token, expected "{" (133:15)
>
> 131 |     }
>
> 132 |   },
>
> 133 |     $(document).ready(function() {

I appreciate for the help I can get. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check if you have latest version installed. Make sure you have referred the JQuery script properly. If everything is right, hard reload your browser by pressing Ctrl + R. This should fix the issue.

Comment: @RohanRao is right, and please check if you installed jQuery correctly.

Comment: If the only purpose of jQuery is standard server interaction, there's no need for it, just use Axios.

Comment: Just as a side note, if you're using Vue, there is no reason you should ever use jQuery.